# how to to transform an object to a string php

Tags: php, oop

I am using the [googl-php](https://github.com/sebi/googl-php) class to create a small url.

I have used the code:

```
require_once('Googl.class.php');

$googl = new Googl('xxxxxxx');

$googl->shorten('http://www.example.co.uk/bitsandbobs.php#martello-tower-y-by-billings-jackson-design');

$myText = (string)$googl;
unset($googl);
```

but this just returns

> Object of class Googl could not be converted to string

Comment: I'm not familiar with the class, but have you checked the return value of the `shorten()` method?

Comment: $googl->shorten returns a json_decode which returns a dynamic value depending on what the URL returns, so without knowing the actual URL, we can't help you other than to say: You can't cast $googl as a string. Try instead a `print_r($googl)` and see what it gives you.

Comment: someone just posted an answer that was correct.... and now it has been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$myText = $googl->shorten(
  'http://www.example.co.uk/bitsandbobs.php#martello-tower-y-by-billings-jackson-design'
);
```

This answer is based on the the published code that you provided a link for

Answer (score 0):

Probably google class doesn't have magic method __toString and you are not able do this.